# Dynamic programming: maximize value of arithmetic expression using parenthesis

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is an interview question asked to me sometime back:

> Suppose you are given an expression E= x1 y1 x2 y2....yn-1 xn.
>
> Where Xi belong to natural number and Yi belongs to { +,*}
>
> you need to parenthesize such that it maximize the value of E ?

I was able to think in the direction of Dynamic Programming and could related it to [matrix chain multiplication problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication#A_Dynamic_Programming_Algorithm), but was stuck on deriving the exact recursive relation for this one.

Moreover, follow-up questions just complicated the situation for me:

> Let's change Yi to { +,-,*,/}, then how to maximize E? Now add %
> operator in that set..then how to maximize E?

An explanation on to how to approach and build a solution for this would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the same relation to the matrix multiplication algorithm will work.

The function we are trying to compute is

```
F(i,j) = maximum number that can be computed using Xi ... Xj
```

The base case is when we have a single number:

```
F(i,i) = Xi
```

And the recursive case is for operations between two subexpressions wrapped in parenthesis:

```
F(i,j) = for k = i,j-1, maximize
    F(i,k) Yk F(k+1, j)
```

I think greedly maximizing the numbers should work because for multiplication and addition over positive numbers, we want both the operands to be as big as possible.

If we allow division, then we will want the second operand to be as small as possible to maximize the result. In that case, instead of just computing `F`, you will also need to compute a similar `G` that minimizes the value over the interval.

If we allow subtraction, then we will need to account for positive vs negative numbersd. If you keep track of largets positive, smallest positive, largest negative and smallest negative I think you should be able to get any values you need. Perhaps there is an alternative that requires less computation though.

I didn't stop to think about the implications of `%`. For starters, how does it behave with the non-integer results from `/`?

Answer (score 2):

By dynamic programming, you can compute the maximum expression possible between Xi and Xj assuming that you put outer parantheses around Xi and Xj. Your dynamic programming recursion involves iterating over all the ways you can insert a pair of adjacent sets of parantheses inside your assumed outer parantheses, and computing the maximum possible value from the maximum possible value for all the sub-cases. This naively gives an O(n^3) time algorithm if you have n terms.

When you allow division and subtraction, things become much more complicated somewhat in contrast to what was suggested by another answer. For example, if you want to maximize and you have division then you want to maximize the numerator if the maximum is positive and make the denominator as close to 1 as possible while staying POSITIVE, or you want to minimize the numerator if the minimum is negative and make the denominator as close to -1 as possible while staying NEGATIVE. And if the signs of the numerator and denominator cannot match, then you want to minimize the magnitude of the numerator and maximize the magnitude of the denominator. The last case is not hard, but the first two cases seem highly non-trivial. How are you going to get as close to 1 or -1 as possible while maintaining the sign, if you are allowed to use all 4 arithmetic operations? This might even be an NP-hard problem, especially if you include the modulus operation as well.